# Trying to replace a row after computing bigram BOW gives Inconsistent shape error

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to compute bigram BOW of each file and replace a row in each iteration of a scipy csr_matrix.Since I got 10868 files and max BOW features 66049, I have defined my final vector of `bytebigram_vect = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix((10868, 66049))`.
In each iteration i am supposed to get 1,66049 which I want to replace with a row in bytebigram_vect. My code gives Inconsistent shape error.

```
vector = CountVectorizer(lowercase=False,ngram_range=(2,2), vocabulary=byte_bigram_vocab)
bytebigram_vect = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix((10868, 66049))
for i in range(len(byte_file_name)):
  # Downloading only a single byte file from train.7z
  
  file_name=byte_file_name[i]
  !7z e train.7z -o/content/bytefiles *$file_name -r
  f = open('bytefiles/' + file_name)
  bytebigram_vect[i:]+= scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(vector.fit_transform([f.read().replace('\n', ' ').lower()]))
  # Deleting the file
  os.remove(file_name)
  f.close()
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-352aa3807cfd> in <module>()
      8   get_ipython().system('7z e train.7z -o/content/bytefiles *$file_name -r')
      9   f = open('bytefiles/' + file_name)
---> 10   bytebigram_vect[i:]+= scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(vector.fit_transform([f.read().replace('\n', ' ').lower()]))
     11   # Deleting the file
     12   os.remove(file_name)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py in __add__(self, other)
    416         elif isspmatrix(other):
    417             if other.shape != self.shape:
--> 418                 raise ValueError("inconsistent shapes")
    419             return self._add_sparse(other)
    420         elif isdense(other):

ValueError: inconsistent shapes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bytebigram_vect[i]= scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(vector.fit_transform([f.read().replace('\n', ' ').lower()]))
```

just replaing this line has helped me achieve it